# How to create a categorical variable in which are reported the name of dummy variable when result interger value 1 in SAS

Tags: loops, sas, categorical-data

someone can help me to generate a categorical variable in SAS?

I have a dataset like this

| K234 | K234 | K24a34 | K34j43 | k... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | .. |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... |

I don't know how obtain a one categorical variable that concat the names of dummy variables where is reported the integer value 1.

The result that i whish to obtein is like this:

| type |
| --- |
| K234-K34j43 |
| K234-K24a34 |
| K234-K24a34-K34j43 |

thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- VNAME() to get the variable name
- ARRAY for dealing with multiple variables
- CATX() for separators in concatenated variables

```
data want;
set have;

length type $200;

array _k_list(*) K: ; *list of variables to scan for 1s;

do i=1 to dim(_k_list);

if _k_list(i) = 1 then
      type = catx("-", type, vname(_k_list(i)));
end;

run;
```

Comment: @HeisembergCox fixed and tested.

Comment: perfect, i found my error in imput, thank you !